# ZfcUser and existing user account passwords

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm using ZfcUser with BjyAuthorize and everything works fine. On project I'm working I have old database that contains users accounts and passwords crypted with MySQL function 'password' and my question is if it's possible to rehash passwords to ZfcUser password type without sending information to all users? My goal is to old user logs in to new system with his old password and script convert somehow this password to ZfcUser standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution, first I found MySQL password function in php:

```
function mysql_password_hash($input, $hex = true)
{
   $sha1_stage1 = sha1($input, true);
   $output = sha1($sha1_stage1, !$hex);
   return strtoupper('*'.$output);
}
```

Then in ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db.php I've added afeter `$bcrypt = new Bcrypt();` these two lines:

```
if(mysql_password_hash($credential) === $userObject->getPassword())
    $this->updateUserPasswordHash($userObject, $credential, $bcrypt);
```

And now during login old MySQL password is rehashed to new Bcrypt password. Maybe it will help somebody.